# Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 5

Tags: html, css

I've tried this code on local and it works fine, but I uploaded it into my live website and shows error "Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 5."

```
   :root{
    --myBlack: #0D0D0D;
    --myBlack2: #262626;
    --myGrey: #8C8C8C;
    --myWhite: #D9D9D9;
    --myGold: #D9AA52;
}
body{
    background-color: var(--myBlack);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

It makes no sense to me since this works perfect on local...

Comment: you are probably using an old validator that doesn't recognize CSS variables. You can ignore the errors

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif , I'll just ignore them then

Answer (score 0):

Why is this an issue?

Stylesheets with syntax errors become invalid and browsers may fail to parse them. This problem is usually caused by mistyped characters.